# Buildroot: install and build the toolchain only

Tags: linux, embedded, buildroot

I want to install and build just the toolchain for my Buildroot project. `make help` suggests that the command `make <options> toolchain` should work; however, running that command simply returns `Nothing to be done for 'toolchain'.` and `output/host` is never created.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You first have to configure Buildroot in order to instruct it about what toolchain you want to produce. See [Buildroot quick start](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_buildroot_quick_start) in the Buildroot user manual.

If you just downloaded Buildroot, the steps to produce a toolchain are:

1. run `make menuconfig`

- In `Target options` select your hardware platform and ABI
- In `Toolchain` configure the kind of toolchain you want
- exit saving

2. run `make toolchain`

The toolchain is in `output/host/`.

EDIT: if you need a toolchain, build the SDK is possibly better, see the answer by @mxxk

Comment: Buildroot really should give an error when you try to do 'make toolchain' before running configure, so I've submitted http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/776011/

Comment: FYI, Arnout fixed this and now an unconfigured Buildroot will print an error when you run 'make toolchain', instead of the old misleading message.The fix will be in the next Buildroot release, 2017.08. (FYI The change is in commit https://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/commit/?id=503439f99a8b1a7f762ed184082b0c97800ffae5)

Answer (score 3):

A more recent way to build just the toolchain, which can be used both within and outside of Buildroot, is documented in the [Buildroot manual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html).

Though `make toolchain` in Luca's answer does build the toolchain, it also places other host dependencies into `output/host/`, making it slightly more difficult to get a clean toolchain as compared to `make sdk` below, which produces a toolchain tarball in `output/images/`:

> #### 6.1.3. Build an external toolchain with Buildroot
>
> The Buildroot internal toolchain option can be used to create an external toolchain. Here are a series of steps to build an internal toolchain and package it up for reuse by Buildroot itself (or other projects).
>
> Create a new Buildroot configuration, with the following details:
>
> - Select the appropriate **Target options** for your target CPU architecture
> - In the **Toolchain** menu, keep the default of **Buildroot toolchain** for **Toolchain type**, and configure your toolchain as desired
> - In the **System configuration** menu, select **None** as the **Init system** and **none** as **/bin/sh**
> - In the **Target packages** menu, disable **BusyBox**
> - In the **Filesystem images** menu, disable **tar the root filesystem**
>
> Then, we can trigger the build, and also ask Buildroot to generate a SDK. This will conveniently generate for us a tarball which contains our toolchain:
>
> ```
> make sdk
> ```
>
> This produces the SDK tarball in `$(O)/images`, with a name similar to `arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabi_sdk-buildroot.tar.gz`. Save this tarball, as it is now the toolchain that you can re-use as an external toolchain in other Buildroot projects.